# Slidescroll javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am having difficulty setting up slidescroll- I've been working on this particular div for days and have revised my question several times. I believe I now have exactly what I need to scroll content vertically in a div using up and down images. But I cannot get this code working-- though it seems to work fine at Scripterlative, where I found it.

I am trying to configure the slidescroll javascript to use with two up/down images placed at a fixed position; the directions in the js file are a bit ambiguous in places and I was hoping for a little help. Not sure what is causing the problem.

***UPDATE

I can now scroll down, but not up. And down scrolls at the speed of light, slowing abruptly when the mouse leaves the image. Any ideas?***

This is what I have:

```
 HTML/CSS

 <div id="repertoiredetails">
 <div id="repertoirescroll">

 <div class="arrows">
 <img id="upButton" src="images/arrowup.png" title="up" alt="up" width="15" height="28">
 <img id="downButton" src="images/arrowdown.png" title="down" alt="down" width="15" height="28">
 </div>

 <p>content</p>
 </div>
 </div>

 #repertoiredetails {
 background-color:#000;
 width:400px;
  margin-top:140px;
 height:1000px; 
  margin-left:-2px;
  padding-top:5px;
  overflow:hidden;
 }

  #repertoirescroll {
width:100%; 
 }

 #repertoirescroll p {
 text-align:justify;
 text-justify:inter-word; 
 color:#999; 
 font-family:'Arial Narrow', Arial,   sans-serif;
 font-size:13px;
 padding:20px;
}

.arrows {
height:50px;
left:350px;
z-index:999;
top:450px;
position:fixed;
}
```

***UPDATED CODE***
This is placed just beneath the closing div repertoiredetails as directed:

```
<script type='text/javascript' >

new SlideScroll( 'upButton', 'self', 'up');
new SlideScroll( 'downButton', 'self', 'down');
```

and slidescroll.js is in the head. For fixed image links, the js requires the ID of "self."

Any help with this is appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: What error you are getting in error console of browser? Did you add the jquery min file?

Comment: prepare a jsfiddle so i can review your code.

Comment: OK- how do I add the slidescroll.js there?

Comment: Try to find any kind of direct link from the reference site.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JJ08/CFN98/38/ finally able to do this correctly...I need help getting the "up" scrolling to work and to slow down the speed of the scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigate you code and found the problem in slidescroll.js. To fix this issue replace below

```
yStep =  -this.speedFactor * (((vBoth ? this.btnHeight / 2 : this.btnHeight) - my) / (vBoth ? this.btnHeight /2 : this.btnHeight));
```

with

```
yStep =  -this.speedFactor * ((my - (vBoth ? this.btnHeight / 2 : this.btnHeight)) / (vBoth ? this.btnHeight /2 : this.btnHeight));
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: thanks for taking the extra time-- I really appreciate it. Yes, that worked. Any idea how to slow the speed of the scroll? Right now, it is going at the speed of light:)

Comment: The fourth argument in new SlideScroll('downButton', 'self', 'down', 10); may help you.